# How to create on mouseover split screen layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to split my screen Like this [website](http://laurenwickware.com/) which act independently.

I search many words in google and YouTube like

- How to create split screen layout for website
- split screen layout

I got many Templates like that but i didn't get any code to learn that how to create it .Can Anyone Please Help me to do it?

Comment: Do you just want a simple split screen layout? With content on the left and content on the right? Or do you want more of the fancy animations featured on the site you mentioned?

Comment: i Want Animation also

Comment: I'm willing to whip up a step by step tutorial of sorts, but I would like to know your current skill level. On a scale of 1 to 5 what's your experience with html&css and what's your skill with javascript and or jquery?

Comment: My skill in html and css is between 3 and 4 but my skill in javascript and jquery is 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great resource that you could use from Tympanus blueprints called [split layout](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/)

You have to add the required listeners for mouse interactions yourself, this layout more or less gives you the required layout over which you can write your logic.

Comment: I have this resource but i want to do website as i mention above